# Activate microphone on Android studio Emulator (Ventura)

Tags: android-studio

I've created a simple android emulator and am trying to record my computer audio though a recording app downloaded from the store. What i did:

- Started a new project, create a new device and launched it (using Tiramisu), activated the microphone (also used `./adb emu avd hostmicon` to be sure)
- Downloaded a voice recorder app to test it out. Issue is that there is only a sine sound, the audio from the computer don't come in

For the audio routing, i've used blackhole and setup the aggregate device and multi output correctly (i've tried recording my mac screen while playing audio, and it works perfectly).

PS: i'm on mac Ventura 13.3